# ! extra alignment tab error in KableExtra

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kableextra

I am receiving an error

> ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
>    \endtemplate

In table 4, where the problem is occurring, is written in the exact same way as the other tables; the other table knit just fine. When I run the chunk for table 4 it does produce the latex code, but won't knit. Since this is an Rmd file and it posts funny. here are links to both my code and my data.

[code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QByb_mJuagvRjf91UEBbQGE0v-jNJ6zy/view?usp=sharing)

[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aKgvrQATqstIrkT_xucoHZLhdZdQHyWC/view?usp=sharing)

I am unsure what the error is saying. I have tried adding alignment and taking away. forexample,

```
kable(licen_area,
      "latex",
      booktabs=T,
      align="lcc",
      col.names=linebreak(c("Licensure\nArea","Count", "\\%"),align="c"),
      row.names=F,
      escape=F)
```

versus

```
kable(licen_area,
      "latex",
      booktabs=T,
      align="lccc",
      col.names=linebreak(c("Licensure\nArea","Count", "\\%"),align="c"),
      row.names=F, 
      escape=F)
```

I have set up a randomly generated data set using:

````
grad_YR <- sample(c("2012-13", "2014-15","2015-16","2016-17","2017-18"), 150, prob=c(".02",".03",".05",".4",".5"), replace=T)
Degree <- sample(c("BA/BS","Master's"),150,prob=c(".75",".25"),replace=T)
licen_Area1 <- sample(c("Art","Dance","Early Childhood","Elementary","Middle","Secordary"),150,prob=c(".02",".01",".35",".35",".13",".14"),replace=T)
sam_dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(Univ,grad_YR,Degree,licen_Area1))```

Table 4 ran knit with no issues.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kable doesn't like it when there are special characters in the data. In the linked that there are several &'s. I removed those and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

What packages and data are you using?

I think that because the second align has a third "c", if you adjust your code to:

```
kable(licen_area,
      "latex",
      booktabs=T,
      align="lcc",
      col.names=linebreak(c("Licensure\nArea","Count", "\\%"),align="c"),
      row.names=F, 
      escape=F)
```

Comment: I using tidyverse, and Kableextra packages, I have tried the code you have above and got the same error. Table 2 is written the same way and knits just fine.

Comment: could you add in a minimal example using data.frame and a dataset like mtcars instead of providing the excel link?

Comment: when I set up a randomly generated data set, Table 4 knit just fine. There is something going on with this data set specifically. I have included the code in question.